# Continuity and Differentability of a Partial derivative

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Pick the correct statement

**(a)** If $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere, then it is also differentiable everywhere.

**(b)** If $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere, then it also has partial derivatives everywhere.

**(c)** If $f(x,y)$ is continuous everywhere, then its partial derivatives are also continuous everywhere.

**(d)** If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable everywhere, then it is also continuous everywhere.

**(e)** If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable everywhere, then its partial derivatives are defined everywhere.

**(f)** If $f(x,y)$ is differentiable everywhere, then its partial derivatives are continuous everywhere.

**(g)** If $f(x,y)$ has partial derivatives everywhere, then it is continuous everywhere.

**(h)** If $f(x,y)$ has partial derivatives everywhere, then it is differentiable everywhere.

**(i)** If $f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives everywhere, then $f(x,y)$ itself is continuous everywhere.

(j)If $f(x,y)$ has continuous partial derivatives everywhere, then it is differentiable everywhere

What I did:

I chose statements **(d),(e),(f)** because for a function to be differentiable everywhere its partial derivatives must exists and the function will surely be continuous everywhere. I believe **(j)** is also correct since I know that if all partial derivatives exists and are continuous on a neighborhood than the function is also differentiable along that neighborhood. However I seem to be missing out on some options.Also could anyone explain the three concepts of partial derivative, continuty and differentibility and how to releate them? Thanks.

Comment: I think, d,e,i, j are correct. Partial derivatives can exist, but, that doesn't say much about continuity due to the examples where all linear paths agree but quadratics differ. I hope someone comes along with some specific counter examples soon, I must run.